# WCF SoapHeader on a function call with no request parameter

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service which receives its input from `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage` rather than from any parameters passed in. 
I have no `DataContract`.
How can I implement a `SoapHeader` please?

The interface of my service:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = Namespaces.Example)]
public interface IExample
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ExampleRequests();
}
```

The service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, Namespace = Namespaces.Example)]
public class Example: IExample
{
      public string ExampleRequests(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used https://wcfextras.codeplex.com/ and the SoapHeader attribute in order to accomplish this.

Updated interface:

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = Namespaces.Example)]
    public interface IExample
    {
        [SoapHeader("MyHeader", typeof(MyHeader), Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
        [OperationContract]
        string ExampleRequests();

    }
```

Updated service:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, Namespace = Namespaces.Example)]
    public class Example: IExample
    {

        public string ExampleRequests()
        {
        ...
        MyHeader soapHeader = SoapHeaderHelper.GetInputHeader("MyHeader");
        if (soapHeader == null || soapHeader.Username.IsNullOrEmpty() || !ValidateCredentials(soapHeader))
        {
        return "You do not have permission to access this service";
        }
        ...
        }

        private bool ValidateCredentials(MyHeader soapHeader)
        {
        if (soapHeader.Username == "admin" && soapHeader.Password == "123")
        {
        return true; 
        }
        return false;
        }

    }
```

MyHeader class:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.Example)]
    public class MyHeader
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```